# Create new column based on presence/absence of string in other column by group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation, tibble

I have this dataset about vessels locations, where the same "id" can correspond to two levels. Corresponds to a defined category, such as "fishing" and may also appear as "unspecified". I would like to create a new column, where whenever an "id" appears as "unspecified" and also as another category (in other rows), "unspecified" is replaced by that category.

```
#dataset example
library(dplyr)

levels <- c("passenger", "passenger", "unspecified", "passenger", "passenger",
            "passenger", "passenger", "passenger", "passenger", "passenger",
            "unspecified", "passenger", "fishing", "unspecified", "fishing", 
            "fishing", "fishing","unspecified", "fishing", "fishing", 
            "unspecified","fishing", "fishing", "fishing", "unspecified",
            "unspecified", "unspecified")
id <- c("844", "844", "844", "844", "844","844", "844", "844", "844", "844",
        "844", "844", "845", "845", "845", "845", "845","845", "845", "845", 
        "845","845", "845", "845", "825", "825", "825")
lat <- c(-30.6456, -29.5648, -27.6667, -31.5587, -30.6934, -29.3147, -23.0538, 
         -26.5877, -26.6923, -23.40865, -23.1143, -23.28331, -31.6456, -24.5648, 
         -27.6867, -31.4587, -30.6784, -28.3447, -23.0466, -27.5877, -26.8524, 
         -23.8855, -24.1143, -23.5874, -23.5259, -22.8788, -22.1324)
long <- c(-50.4879, -49.8715, -51.8716, -50.4456, -50.9842, -51.9787, -41.2343, 
          -40.2859, -40.19599, -41.64302, -41.58042, -41.55057, -50.4576, -48.8715, 
          -51.4566, -51.4456, -50.4477, -50.9937, -41.4789, -41.3859, -40.2536, 
          -41.6502, -40.5442, -41.4057, -40.4058, -42.4877, -41.4545)

df <- tibble(levels = as.factor(levels), id  = as.factor(id), lat, long)
```

Here is my expected output:

```
> output %>% print(n = 27)
# A tibble: 27 x 5
   levels      id      lat  long new_colum  
   <fct>       <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>      
 1 passenger   844   -30.6 -50.5 passenger  
 2 passenger   844   -29.6 -49.9 passenger  
 3 unspecified 844   -27.7 -51.9 passenger  
 4 passenger   844   -31.6 -50.4 passenger  
 5 passenger   844   -30.7 -51.0 passenger  
 6 passenger   844   -29.3 -52.0 passenger  
 7 passenger   844   -23.1 -41.2 passenger  
 8 passenger   844   -26.6 -40.3 passenger  
 9 passenger   844   -26.7 -40.2 passenger  
10 passenger   844   -23.4 -41.6 passenger  
11 unspecified 844   -23.1 -41.6 passenger  
12 passenger   844   -23.3 -41.6 passenger  
13 fishing     845   -31.6 -50.5 fishing    
14 unspecified 845   -24.6 -48.9 fishing    
15 fishing     845   -27.7 -51.5 fishing    
16 fishing     845   -31.5 -51.4 fishing    
17 fishing     845   -30.7 -50.4 fishing    
18 unspecified 845   -28.3 -51.0 fishing    
19 fishing     845   -23.0 -41.5 fishing    
20 fishing     845   -27.6 -41.4 fishing    
21 unspecified 845   -26.9 -40.3 fishing    
22 fishing     845   -23.9 -41.7 fishing    
23 fishing     845   -24.1 -40.5 fishing    
24 fishing     845   -23.6 -41.4 fishing    
25 unspecified 825   -23.5 -40.4 unspecified
26 unspecified 825   -22.9 -42.5 unspecified
27 unspecified 825   -22.1 -41.5 unspecified
```

It's for when the same `id` is `unspecified` but it's also belongs some other level. When it's just `unspecified` it stays that way, when it also belongs to other level replaces `unspecified` with this one.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of ``new_column``? When does it become `passenger` or `fishing` or `unspecified`?

Comment: Yes. It's for when an "ID" is "unspecified" but it's also some other category. When it's just "unspecified" it stays that way, when it "finds" its other category replaces "unspecified" with it. improved?

Comment: Now that I realized I didn't include the last rows with id that remains 'unspecified'. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `"unspecified"` with `NA`, fill these `NA` with the previous value in the same `id` group, and then replace the remaining `NA` back to `"unspecified"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(new_colum = na_if(levels, "unspecified")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(new_colum) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  replace_na(list(new_colum = "unspecified"))
```

```r
# A tibble: 27 × 5
   levels      id      lat  long new_colum  
   <fct>       <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>      
 1 passenger   844   -30.6 -50.5 passenger  
 2 passenger   844   -29.6 -49.9 passenger  
 3 unspecified 844   -27.7 -51.9 passenger  
 4 passenger   844   -31.6 -50.4 passenger  
 5 passenger   844   -30.7 -51.0 passenger  
 6 passenger   844   -29.3 -52.0 passenger  
 7 passenger   844   -23.1 -41.2 passenger  
 8 passenger   844   -26.6 -40.3 passenger  
 9 passenger   844   -26.7 -40.2 passenger  
10 passenger   844   -23.4 -41.6 passenger  
11 unspecified 844   -23.1 -41.6 passenger  
12 passenger   844   -23.3 -41.6 passenger  
13 fishing     845   -31.6 -50.5 fishing    
14 unspecified 845   -24.6 -48.9 fishing    
15 fishing     845   -27.7 -51.5 fishing    
16 fishing     845   -31.5 -51.4 fishing    
17 fishing     845   -30.7 -50.4 fishing    
18 unspecified 845   -28.3 -51.0 fishing    
19 fishing     845   -23.0 -41.5 fishing    
20 fishing     845   -27.6 -41.4 fishing    
21 unspecified 845   -26.9 -40.3 fishing    
22 fishing     845   -23.9 -41.7 fishing    
23 fishing     845   -24.1 -40.5 fishing    
24 fishing     845   -23.6 -41.4 fishing    
25 unspecified 825   -23.5 -40.4 unspecified
26 unspecified 825   -22.9 -42.5 unspecified
27 unspecified 825   -22.1 -41.5 unspecified
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the simplest/most intuitive solution:

The `case_when` statement checks each group - if all `levels` are `"unspecified"`, then `new_column` becomes `"unspecified"`, otherwise if it contains either `"fishing"` or `"passenger"`, it becomes one of those.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(new_column = case_when(
        all(levels == "unspecified") ~ "unspecified",
        any(levels == "fishing") ~ "fishing",
        any(levels == "passenger") ~ "passenger"
        )
    )
```

```
# A tibble: 27 × 5
# Groups:   id [3]
   levels      id      lat  long new_column 
   <fct>       <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
 1 passenger   844   -30.6 -50.5 passenger  
 2 passenger   844   -29.6 -49.9 passenger  
 3 unspecified 844   -27.7 -51.9 passenger  
 4 passenger   844   -31.6 -50.4 passenger  
 5 passenger   844   -30.7 -51.0 passenger  
 6 passenger   844   -29.3 -52.0 passenger  
 7 passenger   844   -23.1 -41.2 passenger  
 8 passenger   844   -26.6 -40.3 passenger  
 9 passenger   844   -26.7 -40.2 passenger  
10 passenger   844   -23.4 -41.6 passenger  
11 unspecified 844   -23.1 -41.6 passenger  
12 passenger   844   -23.3 -41.6 passenger  
13 fishing     845   -31.6 -50.5 fishing    
14 unspecified 845   -24.6 -48.9 fishing    
15 fishing     845   -27.7 -51.5 fishing    
16 fishing     845   -31.5 -51.4 fishing    
17 fishing     845   -30.7 -50.4 fishing    
18 unspecified 845   -28.3 -51.0 fishing    
19 fishing     845   -23.0 -41.5 fishing    
20 fishing     845   -27.6 -41.4 fishing    
21 unspecified 845   -26.9 -40.3 fishing    
22 fishing     845   -23.9 -41.7 fishing    
23 fishing     845   -24.1 -40.5 fishing    
24 fishing     845   -23.6 -41.4 fishing    
25 unspecified 825   -23.5 -40.4 unspecified
26 unspecified 825   -22.9 -42.5 unspecified
27 unspecified 825   -22.1 -41.5 unspecified
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ifelse` statement to specify condition where there is only one type of `levels` **AND** at the same time that `levels` equals to "unspecified", do not change these records. Otherwise, change it to another `levels` that is not "unspecified".

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(new_column = ifelse(n_distinct(levels) == 1 & levels == "unspecified",
                             as.character(levels), 
                             as.character(levels)[levels != "unspecified"]))

# A tibble: 27 × 5
# Groups:   id [3]
   levels      id      lat  long new_column 
   <fct>       <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
 1 passenger   844   -30.6 -50.5 passenger  
 2 passenger   844   -29.6 -49.9 passenger  
 3 unspecified 844   -27.7 -51.9 passenger  
 4 passenger   844   -31.6 -50.4 passenger  
 5 passenger   844   -30.7 -51.0 passenger  
 6 passenger   844   -29.3 -52.0 passenger  
 7 passenger   844   -23.1 -41.2 passenger  
 8 passenger   844   -26.6 -40.3 passenger  
 9 passenger   844   -26.7 -40.2 passenger  
10 passenger   844   -23.4 -41.6 passenger  
11 unspecified 844   -23.1 -41.6 passenger  
12 passenger   844   -23.3 -41.6 passenger  
13 fishing     845   -31.6 -50.5 fishing    
14 unspecified 845   -24.6 -48.9 fishing    
15 fishing     845   -27.7 -51.5 fishing    
16 fishing     845   -31.5 -51.4 fishing    
17 fishing     845   -30.7 -50.4 fishing    
18 unspecified 845   -28.3 -51.0 fishing    
19 fishing     845   -23.0 -41.5 fishing    
20 fishing     845   -27.6 -41.4 fishing    
21 unspecified 845   -26.9 -40.3 fishing    
22 fishing     845   -23.9 -41.7 fishing    
23 fishing     845   -24.1 -40.5 fishing    
24 fishing     845   -23.6 -41.4 fishing    
25 unspecified 825   -23.5 -40.4 unspecified
26 unspecified 825   -22.9 -42.5 unspecified
27 unspecified 825   -22.1 -41.5 unspecified
```